# how to download many images form internet

Tags: android

i want to download many images form internet,first when download  fixed qty  images i refresh the UI,then download other images ,so that this give people good experience.at present i know one method:when downloaded the fixed qty  images,i add one view at  the bottom,tell people that :"there are other images ,do you go on download" when people click it ,then go on download,but i think the method not good.can you give me more experience, i want to Display one image while download one image,not download  finish then show pic.i hope download and show at the sametime.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for downloading images in the background and then updating the UI in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: yes,at present i used the AsyncTask ,but dobackground not at once give value to onPostExecute(),dobackground finished,then onPostExecute(),i want to know if have a methods when dobackground download one image at once to give onPostExecute()